# Auto Scaling for EC2 Celery workers with ASG or Spot Fleets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

I want to setup auto scaling of EC2 instances on my celery cluster, and I've been doing this manually spinning up new EC2 instances whenever I see (manually) that the SQS queue experiences low throughput.

Searching around, I've came across two seemingly similar solutions:

- `AutoScalingGroup` with EC2 Intances using `LaunchConfiguration`s configured to use Spot Instances
- `SpotFleet` with direct response actions to SQS metrics

Most questions on SO are dated (6 months is not much, but it's basically the release date of `SpotFleet` auto scaling feature) and mention that `SpotFleet` lacks ASG features.

Particularly concerning: running the Celery worker will require me to run some setup (install package, download code, run some script). I'm not particularly worried about cost (both are spot instances, close enough) and reliability (workers can die without a problem, the exact size of the cluster is not that important either).

Which option will work as best practice to get this done?